# MySQL selecting rows with a max id and matching other conditions

Tags: mysql, max

Using the tables below as an example and the listed query as a base query, I want to add a way to select only rows with a max id! Without having to do a second query!

```
TABLE VEHICLES

id      vehicleName
-----   --------
1       cool car
2       cool car
3       cool bus
4       cool bus
5       cool bus
6       car
7       truck
8       motorcycle
9       scooter
10      scooter
11      bus

TABLE VEHICLE NAMES

nameId  vehicleName
------  -------
1       cool car
2       cool bus
3       car
4       truck
5       motorcycle
6       scooter
7       bus

TABLE VEHICLE ATTRIBUTES

nameId  attribute
------  ---------
1       FAST
1       SMALL
1       SHINY
2       BIG
2       SLOW
3       EXPENSIVE
4       SHINY
5       FAST
5       SMALL
6       SHINY
6       SMALL
7       SMALL
```

And the base query:

```
select a.*
  from vehicle         a
  join vehicle_names   b using(vehicleName)
  join vehicle_attribs c using(nameId)
 where c.attribute in('SMALL', 'SHINY')
 and a.vehicleName like '%coo%'
 group 
    by a.id
having count(distinct c.attribute) = 2;
```

So what I want to achieve is to select rows with certain attributes, that match a name but only one entry for each name that matches where the id is the highest!

So a working solution in this example would return the below rows:

```
id      vehicleName
-----   --------
2       cool car
10      scooter
```

if it was using some sort of max on the id

at the moment I get all the entries for cool car and scooter.

My real world database follows a similar structure and has 10's of thousands of entries in it so a query like above could easily return 3000+ results. I limit the results to 100 rows to keep execution time low as the results are used in a search on my site. The reason I have repeats of "vehicles" with the same name but only a different ID is that new models are constantly added but I keep the older one around for those that want to dig them up! But on a search by car name I don't want to return the older cards just the newest one which is the one with the highest ID!

The correct answer would adapt the query I provided above that I'm currently using and have it only return rows where the name matches but has the highest id!

If this isn't possible, suggestions on how I can achieve what I want without massively increasing the execution time of a search would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have index on `vehicle_attribs` on `(nameId, attribute)` ? And search on vehicle_names using `LIKE '%cool%'` is NOT using any index

Comment: @ajreal there is a PRIMARY KEY on (nameId,  attribute) in the vehicle_attribs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to keep your logic, here what I would do:

```
select a.*
from vehicle a
    left join vehicle a2 on (a.vehicleName = a2.vehicleName and a.id < a2.id)
    join vehicle_names   b on (a.vehicleName = b.vehicleName)
    join vehicle_attribs c using(nameId)
where c.attribute in('SMALL', 'SHINY')
    and a.vehicleName like '%coo%'
    and a2.id is null
group by a.id
having count(distinct c.attribute) = 2;
```

Which yield:

```
+----+-------------+
| id | vehicleName |
+----+-------------+
|  2 | cool car    |
| 10 | scooter     |
+----+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As other said, normalization could be done on few levels:

Keeping your current `vehicle_names` table as the primary lookup table, I would change:

```
update vehicle a
    inner join vehicle_names b using (vehicleName)
set a.vehicleName = b.nameId;
alter table vehicle change column vehicleName nameId int;

create table attribs (
    attribId int auto_increment primary key,
    attribute varchar(20),
    unique key attribute (attribute)
);
insert into attribs (attribute)
    select distinct attribute from vehicle_attribs;
update vehicle_attribs a
    inner join attribs b using (attribute)
set a.attribute=b.attribId;
alter table vehicle_attribs change column attribute attribId int;
```

Which led to the following query:

```
select a.id, b.vehicleName
from vehicle a
    left join vehicle a2 on (a.nameId = a2.nameId and a.id < a2.id)
    join vehicle_names b on (a.nameId = b.nameId)
    join vehicle_attribs c on (a.nameId=c.nameId)
    inner join attribs d using (attribId)
where d.attribute in ('SMALL', 'SHINY')
    and b.vehicleName like '%coo%'
    and a2.id is null
group by a.id
having count(distinct d.attribute) = 2;
```

Comment: Nice way of ranking when you need a single record from each group, I have not thought of it. I would suggest a solution with variables, but this one is much better, since the results of the query might be cached in the query cache.

Answer (score 3):

The table does not seems normalized, however this facilitate you to do this :

```
select max(id), vehicleName
from VEHICLES
group by vehicleName
having count(*)>=2;
```

Comment: the table is just a sample quite different to the real thing! Is the group by important to the max? But what I'm really after in an answer is what would i add to the query I provided above to select only the max rows! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand your model, but the following query satisfies your requirements as they stand. The first sub query finds the latest version of the vehicle. The second query satisfies your "and" condition. Then I just join the queries on vehiclename (which is the key?).

```
select a.id
      ,a.vehiclename
  from (select a.vehicleName, max(id) as id
          from vehicle a
         where vehicleName like '%coo%'
        group by vehicleName
       ) as a
  join (select b.vehiclename
          from vehicle_names   b
          join vehicle_attribs c using(nameId)
         where c.attribute in('SMALL', 'SHINY') 
        group by b.vehiclename
        having count(distinct c.attribute) = 2
       ) as b on (a.vehicleName = b.vehicleName);
```

If this "latest vehicle" logic is something you will need to do a lot, a small suggestion would be to create a view (see below) which returns the latest version of each vehicle. Then you could use the view instead of the find-max-query. Note that this is purely for ease-of-use, it offers no performance benefits.

```
select *
  from vehicle a
 where id = (select max(b.id)
               from vehicle b
              where a.vehiclename = b.vehiclename);
```

Comment: VIEWS are not indexed, so it may not accelerate the query results with the amount of records the OP has.

Comment: @Danosaure: I'll edit my answer to make it clearer that my suggestion was meant to improve ease of use.

Answer (score 0):

Without going into proper redesign of you model you could

1) Add a column IsLatest that your application could manage.

This is not perfect but will satisfy you question (until next problem, see not at the end)
All you need is when you add a new entry to issue queries such as

```
UPDATE a
SET IsLatest = 0
WHERE IsLatest = 1

INSERT new a

UPDATE a
SET IsLatest = 1
WHERE nameId = @last_inserted_id
```

in a transaction or a trigger

2) Alternatively you can find out the max_id before you issue your query

```
SELECT MAX(nameId)
FROM a
WHERE vehicleName = @name
```

3) You can do it in single SQL, and providing indexes on (vehicleName, nameId) it should actually have decent speed with

```
select a.*
  from vehicle         a
  join vehicle_names   b ON a.vehicleName = b.vehicleName
  join vehicle_attribs c ON b.nameId = c.nameId AND c.attribute = 'SMALL'
  join vehicle_attribs d ON b.nameId = c.nameId AND d.attribute = 'SHINY'
  join vehicle         notmax ON a.vehicleName = b.vehicleName AND a.nameid < notmax.nameid 
 where a.vehicleName like '%coo%'
       AND notmax.id IS NULL
```

I have removed your GROUP BY and HAVING and replaced it with another join (assuming that only single attribute per nameId is possible).

I have also used one of the ways to find max per group and that is to join a table on itself and filter out a row for which there are no records that have a bigger id for a same name.

There are other ways, search so for 'max per group sql'. Also see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html), though not complete.

Comment: Nice, I never thought of implementing "small AND shiny" as a join.